# WSO2 API Analytics: how to access API_REQUEST_SUMMARY table

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

Can some please help me how to find the table API_REQUEST_SUMMARY table. I am using Data explorer in API Analytics homepage and search and searching with table name as    ORG_WSO2_APIMGT_STATISTICS_PERDAYREQUEST.
The details which are showing in the result is correct but how can I access the table which it is storing these data.

Comment: check the STAT_DB

Answer (score 0):

The api_prod_stat DB contains all informations to retrieve statistics.